# Simulating static constructors in C++?

Tags: c++, syntax

Is there anyway I can modify this code example

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    Base() {
        if(!m_initialized) {
            static_constructor();
            m_initialized = true;
        }
    }
protected:
    virtual void static_constructor() {
        std::cout << "Base::static_constructor()\n";
    }
private:
    static bool m_initialized;
};

bool Base::m_initialized = false;

class Derived : public Base {
    void static_constructor() {
        std::cout << "Derived::static_constructor()\n";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Derived d;
    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

So that `Derived::static_constructor()` gets called instead of the Base's? I want to initialize a bunch of static variables, and the most logical place to do it is somewhere in the class.

Comment: Just realized that I can't really use `m_initialized` because then only one derived class would ever get initialized anyway...

Comment: Do I basically just have to copy the code from the base into every single derived class?

Comment: Not directly; but there are ways of getting what you want. Do you need initializers run at startup or first instantiation?

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to achieve?

Comment: @bdonlan: Doesn't really matter. First instantiation would be better I guess.
@Jim: A member function for initializing static members? I can't initialize them in global space like m_initialized is because I have to perform a few operations on them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I adopted this solution from the solution by Martin V Lowis. The main differences are that it uses multiple inheritance, and the CRTP:

```
template<class T>
class StaticInitializer : public T
{
  static bool initialized;
 public:
  StaticInitializer(){
    if(!initialized){
      T::static_constructor();
      initialized=true;
    }
  }
};

template<class T> bool StaticInitializer<T>::initialized;

class Base : public StaticInitializer<Base>
{
public:
  static void static_constructor() {
    std::cout << "Base::static_constructor()\n";
  }
};
static Base _base;

class Derived : public Base, public StaticInitializer<Derived>
{
public:
    static void static_constructor() {
      std::cout << "Derived::static_constructor()\n";
    }
};
static Derived _derived;
```

Each concrete subclass of StaticInitializer gets it's own static constructor initialisation method, but you keep the advantage of having true inheritance.

Comment: Ah! Now that's better. It's unfortunate that you have to inherit from StaticInitializer in the derived class, but I suppose that's the best we can do. Very cool! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You should never call virtual functions from the constructor (or destructor)! The result will not be as "expected" (hence the result you see). Why? Because the base constructor (Base) is called before the Derived constructor. This means that the local datamembers in Derived, which the virtual function may refer to, are not initialized yet. In addition, and maybe even more importantly, the [vtable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) has not been initialized with functions in Derived yet, only with members from Base. Hence, the virtual function isn't really virtual yet - it won't be untill Base() completes and Derived() is processed.

Also, doing this would break the [Open/Closed-principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) which in short reads "classes should be open for extension, but closed for modification". You are by altering the Base static initialization trying to modify its behavior rather than extending it. It might seem like a good idea at the time, but chances are it will bite your ass later on ;)

Comment: Ahh.. that makes sense. It doesn't answer my question, but it's a very helpful explanation. +1

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid duplication of the boolean variable with a template class. Declare an instance of the of the template whose constructor will run the static initializer. Make the instance static, so that inclusion of the header file will automatically declare a static object.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class StaticInitializer{
  static bool initialized;
 public:
  StaticInitializer(){
    if(!initialized){
      T::static_constructor();
      initialized=true;
    }
  }
};

template<class T> bool StaticInitializer<T>::initialized;

class Base{
public:
  static void static_constructor() {
    std::cout << "Base::static_constructor()\n";
  }
};
static StaticInitializer<Base> _base;

class Derived{
public:
    static void static_constructor() {
      std::cout << "Derived::static_constructor()\n";
    }
};
static StaticInitializer<Derived> _derived;

int main()
{}
```

Comment: As nice as this solution is... then base and derived are of type `StaticInitializer` and I can't use their other member functions...

Answer (score 0):

I propose this solution:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

class Object {
public:
    Object() {
        std::cout << m_var << std::endl;
    }
private:
    static int m_var, init_var();
};

int Object::init_var() {
    return 5;
}

int Object::m_var = Object::init_var();

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Object o;
    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

This way `m_var` only gets initialized once, and I keep all the construction code inside the class.